# How can I delete an item from Message Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, message

I know it must be an easy question. But I couldnt find any solution. I have a message array;

```
Message[] messages;
```

And it has 9 item and I want to delete one of them when I click the button. But I couldnt find any remove or delete function for that.

What I want to do is something like:

```
messages[1].remove;
```

or

```
messages.remove(1);
```

And then my array has 8 item. I am working on Eclipse-Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Message[] removeFromArray(Message[] array, int index)
{
    int length = array.length;
    if(index < 0 || index >= length) return array;

    Message temp = new Message[length - 1];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(i == index) continue;
        temp[counter++] = array[i];
    }
    return temp;
}

// ...

Message[] messages = getMessageArraySomeHow();
messages = removeFromArray(messages, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an ArrayList instead of an array for your messages? In that case, you can use [ArrayList.remove(index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) method.

ex:

```
ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
messages.remove(1);
```

if you can't use an Arraylist by default,

```
ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(messages));
messageList.remove(1);
```

Comment: I couldnt do that because I have to receive the messages like : messages = folder.getMessages(); and because of this reason I have to use Messages[]. But I will try now to copy the messages to an Arraylist<Message> then I can remove maybe it can solve

Comment: for that, there is an easier method. Edited my answer.